# Search in Javascript object by index string value

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to iterate through an multidimensional object. I have string, which i have to match in the object index and get that value.
for eg:

```
var datasets = {
    "usa:::west": {
        label: "USA",
        data: [[1988, 483994], [1989, 479060], [1990, 457648], [1991, 401949], [1992, 424705], [1993, 402375], [1994, 377867], [1995, 357382], [1996, 337946], [1997, 336185], [1998, 328611], [1999, 329421], [2000, 342172], [2001, 344932], [2002, 387303], [2003, 440813], [2004, 480451], [2005, 504638], [2006, 528692]]
    },        
    "russia:::north": {
        label: "Russia",
        data: [[1988, 218000], [1989, 203000], [1990, 171000], [1992, 42500], [1993, 37600], [1994, 36600], [1995, 21700], [1996, 19200], [1997, 21300], [1998, 13600], [1999, 14000], [2000, 19100], [2001, 21300], [2002, 23600], [2003, 25100], [2004, 26100], [2005, 31100], [2006, 34700]]
    }
};
```

In this case i only have the string "usa" wherease in the object the index is "usa:::west". How can i search it?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are looking for. If you want to search through the keys in datasets look at http://jsfiddle.net/op9z14ff/ if you want to search deeper as well you'll have to search inside each key as well.

Answer (score 2):

As I understood correctly, this is perhaps something you're after for:

```
var getKeys = function(query) {
  var keys = Object.keys(datasets).filter(function(key) {
    return !!~key.indexOf(query);
  });

  return keys;
};
```

where `getKeys('usa');` returns an array `['usa:::west']`. And for instance `getKeys(':::');` will return `['usa:::west', 'russia:::north']`

Comment: Yes this too works for me. Thanks for the answer. @zvona

Comment: Just a note: In older client environments, `Object.keys` and `Array.filter` are not available (for a breakdown [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) ). `for`/`for..in` may be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to iterate over the keys of your dataset and try to match the beginning of the key:

```
var search = 'usa';
var keys = Object.keys(datasets);
for (var key in keys) {
    if (key.indexOf(search) === 0) {
        var values = datasets[key];
        // from here on you have access to label, data, etc
    }
}
```

Comment: `Object.keys` returns an array, it is considered bad style and can cause problems in some browsers to use `for ... in` on arrays. In a recent browser use `Object.keys(obj).filter(...)` or including older browsers access the array by index.

Comment: vanhelgen is right, my bad for this bad shortcut. You can still iterate with normal array iteration
`for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) { ... }`